# What does 'transmitted' mean in printf function return?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I'm confused the interpretation of `printf`'s return value and buffered stream in Standard C Library.

In [C99:TC3 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), 7.19.6.3/p3 defines that `printf` function returns non-negative "number of characters *transmitted*" in success.
Also, 7.19.3/p3 describes the behaviors of fully/line buffered stream with "*transmitted* to or from the host environment", and p7 says `stdout` can be fully buffered stream.

Quote section 7.19.3 with emphasis added:

> 7.19.3 Files
>
> 3 When a stream is *unbuffered*, characters are intended to appear from the source or at the destination as soon as possible. Otherwise characters may be accumulated and **transmitted to or from the host environment** as a block. When a stream is *fully buffered*, characters are intended to be **transmitted to or from the host environment** as a block when a buffer is filled.
>   When a stream is *line buffered*, characters are intended to be **transmitted to or from the host environment** as a block when a new-line character is encountered. Furthermore, characters are intended to be **transmitted as a block to the host environment** when a buffer is filled, when input is requested on an unbuffered stream, or when input is requested on a line buffered stream that requires the transmission of characters from the host environment. Support for these characteristics is implementation-defined, and may be affected via the `setbuf` and `setvbuf` functions.
>
> 7 [...] As initially opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and **standard output streams are fully buffered** if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device.

These definitions lead the following behavior is legal.
But it's counterintuitive and unacceptable result (at least for me).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

// PRECONDITION: `stdout` is fully buffered
int main()
{
   int n = printf("abc");  // "abc" is accumulated, and no transmission.
   assert(n == 0);         // so, return value can be equal to 0 ??
}
```

What am I wrong in my interpretation?
Or it's only one of "implementation-defined" behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "*transmitted*" implies that the bytes cross some interface. I submit that the interface that 7.19.6.3 refers to is the interface between `printf` and the device driver, whereas the interface that 7.19.3 refers to is the output of the device driver.

Furthermore, I submit that the interpretation you propose would make the return value from `printf` arbitrary and capricious.

Hence, I conclude that the `printf` in your sample code will always return 3.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `printf` and `fprintf` are the number of bytes transmitted to the stream -- which is an object inside of the host environment -- not to the final destination. When and how those bytes are transmitted by the stream to the file or device ("transmitted from the host environment") is irrelevant. Buffering does not affect how the stream accepts bytes from the program; just whether and until when it holds onto them until sending them on to the associated file or device.